# Shortest distance between the origin and a parabola

Tags: geometry

What is the smallest distance between the origin and a point on the graph of $y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (x^2 - 18)?$

I used the distance formula to get
$$\sqrt{x^2 + \frac{1}{2}(x^2-18)^2},$$
but I don't know what to do from there.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Now you want to be using the first derivative of your new expression to find its minimum in terms of $x$

Comment: What is your mathematical background?  This is a bit easier with calculus, but doable with algebra.

Comment: @Teepeemm I am in algebra 2. I haven't learned calculus yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 ways you can solve it. One using basic algebra and other requires calculus.

**I) Completing the Square (Algebra)-** 

This is a classic use case of the completing the square method of factorisation, which is also seen quite a bit in inequalities. So I suggest you try to understand it well.

Here’s how you can approach this question-
$$
Distance = \sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{2}(x^2-18)^2} = \sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{2}(x^4-36x^2 +18^2)} \\
= \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}(x^4)-17x^2 +\frac{1}{2}18^2}
$$
Now we complete the square, by adding or subtracting appropriate terms, such that, $a^2 = \frac{1}{2}x^4, -2ab = -17x^2$ so that we can use the formula $(a-b)^2 = a^2 - 2ab + b^2$
$$
\implies \sqrt{{(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}x^2)^2 - 2(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}x^2)(\frac{17}{\sqrt{2}}) + (\frac{17}{\sqrt{2}})^2 - (\frac{17}{\sqrt{2}})^2 +\frac{1}{2}18^2} \\
\implies \sqrt{{(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}x^2 - \frac{17}{\sqrt{2}})^2 + \frac{18^2}{2} - \frac{17^2}{2}} = \sqrt{{(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}x^2 - \frac{17}{\sqrt{2}})^2 + \frac{35}{2}}
$$

Now the answer lies in the observation that ${(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}x^2 - \frac{17}{\sqrt{2}})^2 \geq 0$, This is because, the square of any real number is never negative, and the least value a perfect square can attain is $0$. This is a very useful tool in many questions, as it allows us to introduce inequalities in places where inequalities haven't been given (So questions like find the maximum or minimum)
Now we may substitute ${(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}x^2 - \frac{17}{\sqrt{2}})^2 = 0$
into our equation to get the least value of distance.
$$
{Distance}_{min} = \sqrt{\frac{35}{2}}
$$
Which is the answer and can be verified.

I will not detail the calculus approach here, as I am not sure if you are familiar with calculus. However, if you want me to, you may ask me in the comments.
Hope it helps!

Comment: What most answers write as $\sqrt{\frac{35}{2}}$, some people prefer to write as $\frac12 \sqrt{70}$.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Reducing a square root of a fraction to a fraction of a square root was useful back when you had to compute things by hand, but totally uninformative otherwise.

Comment: @PasserBy Why do you say it was useful back then? Do you mean today people will use computers/calculators to quickly determine if expressions like $\sqrt{\frac{20}{3}}$ and $\frac23 \sqrt{15}$ are equal or not, whereas when computers did not exist it was meaningful to agree on some "canonical" form so it did not take effort to determine if two answers agreed or differed?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen It's useful because you want to perform square roots on simple numbers, then divide it, rather than the other way around because square roots are comparatively harder. I suppose having a canonical has value, but it isn't obvious which one should be canonical. For one thing, since $\sqrt{\frac{35}{2}}$ pops out naturally here, it would take even more effort to check whether reducing to $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{70}$ is correct.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative approach is as follows:

[image]

The shortest distance is the radius of the smallest circle $$x^2+y^2=r^2$$ that has point of intersection with the parabola $$y=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(x^2-18).$$

Putting the equations together, we have

$$x^2+\frac{1}{2}(x^2-18)^2=r^2$$
$$x^4-34x^2+(324-2r^2)=0$$

The circle intersects the parabola when
$$34^2-4(1)(324-2r^2) \geq 0$$

$$r^2 \geq \frac{35}{2}$$

$$r \geq \sqrt {\frac{35}{2}}$$

Therefore the shortest distance is $\sqrt {\frac{35}{2}}$.

Answer (score 3):

The parametric equation of the parabola is

$ p(t) = ( t, \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (t^2 - 18) ) $

The squared distance from the origin to $p(t)$ is

$ s = p(t) \cdot p(t) $

Differentiating this with respect to $t$ gives us

$ s' = 2 p(t) \cdot p'(t) $

This must be zero.

$ p'(t) = (1, \sqrt{2} t ) $

Therefore, we want

$ t + t (t^2 - 18)  = 0 $

i.e.

$ t (t^2 - 17) = 0 $

The solutions are $ t = 0 $ and $ t = \pm \sqrt{17} $

Now,

$p(0) = (0, - 9 \sqrt{2} ) $  and $ p( \sqrt{17} ) = ( \sqrt{17} , - \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} )$

Therefore,

$s(0) = 162 $ and $ s(\sqrt{17}) = 17.5 $

Hence, the minimum distance is achieved at $t = \pm \sqrt{17} $ and that minimum distance is

$ d = \sqrt{ s (\sqrt{17} ) } = \sqrt{ 17.5 } = \sqrt{\dfrac{35}{2}} $

The two corresponding points on the parabola are

$ ( - \sqrt{17} , - \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} ) $ and $ ( \sqrt{17} , - \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}) $

Answer (score 2):

You can get rid of the square root by observing that out is monotonic over the positive reals. So the square root as a whole is minimal at the point(s) where the expression under the root is minimal.

Now this leaves you with an quartic (degree 4) expression in $x$. But since it only contains even powers of $x$ it's easier to essentially treat $x^2$ as a variable. You can use a new symbol for that, $u:=x^2$. So you have a quadratic expression in $u$ and want to know where that is minimal. That's the case where the derivative is zero. The derivative if a quadratic (degree 2) expression is linear (degree 1) so you get a single value $u$ which satisfies that condition. Assuming it's positive, you then get two values $x_{1,2}=\pm\sqrt u$ which both have the same minimal distance.

Comment: Do you mean "monotonic" (only increasing, or only decreasing) rather than "monotonous" (boring)?

Comment: @psmears Thanks for the correction, my native German doesn't make that distinction. Corrected.

Answer (score 2):

Let $P=(x,y)$ is an arbitrary point on the given curve. For the distance between that point and the origin $O=(0,0)$ will hold
$$d^2(P,O)=(x-0)^2+(y-0)^2=x^2+y^2 = \sqrt2y+18+y^2,$$

and the minimum is achieved for $y=-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2}$, i.e. at the point $P=\left(\sqrt{17},-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2}\right)$. Hence
$$d=\sqrt{17+\frac{1}{2}}=\boxed{\sqrt{\frac{35}{2}}}.$$

Comment: I like that switching to $y$ makes this a quadratic problem instead of a quartic.  But depending on the mathematical maturity of OP, you may need to explain why you know where the minimum is achieved.

Comment: To @Teepeemm: thank you for your comment. There are several approaches how we can determine the minimum for $y^2+\sqrt2 y +18$, i.e. for the quadratic function. One handy approach, for the most students/scholars, is to find the first coordinate of the vertex for the function graph, i.e. for the parabola.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution.  First calculate all points for which the ray from $O$ is perpendicular to the function, i.e.,
$$\frac{y}{x}\cdot y'=-1\iff yy'=-x.$$
In our case we have
$$\sqrt2\cdot x\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x^2-18)=-x,$$
which immediately gives $x^2=17$ or $x=0$ and $y=-1/\sqrt2$ or $y=-18/\sqrt2$, resp. Hence
$$x^2+y^2=17+\frac12\text{ or }17+162 .$$